# How can I make a custom simple dictionary in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I would like to have 3 different "languages" with each mapped to the same single language. The purpose is to be able to translate from Bloomberg's, Factset's, or CapIQ's notation for international stock tickers to a custom notation. I will be inputting a list (normally about 100) of text strings such as:

```
APRL.LN
CMOS.CA
SIN.CA
98553.CN
```

OR

```
APRL-LON
CMOS-CAN
SINT-CAN
98553-CHN
```

and, in either case, need to return:

```
APRL:London
CMOS:Canada
SINT:Canada
98553:China
```

I'm willing to do it in VBA or a simpler way if it exists. Thanks in advance, and please don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: That doesn't look that complicated if you can create a lookup table for each langauge+segment: split on the separator and then join the results. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: @TimWilliams haven't put pen to paper yet, but was wondering how I would go about making it more automated than having to use text to columns or something similar?